Create Multiple Instance of BackgroundService in ASP.NET Core
I am new to this and would appreciate some pointers or examples.
How can I create multiple instances of a BackgroundService in an ASP.NET Core app that process messages from a queue? Should I use BackgroundService or IHostedService ?
Thanks

You can use either since BackGroundService is just an implementation of IHostedService.
Usually you'd want to stick with your implementation of BackgroundService

BackgroundService is a base class for implementing a long running IHostedService.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

IHostedService is an interface that defines two methods: StartAsync(CancellationToken) and StopAsync(CancellationToken). You need to implement the logic for starting and stopping the service.
BackgroundService is an abstract class that implements IHostedService and provides a template method pattern via the ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken) method. You only need to override this method to execute the background task. It handles the starting and stopping processes for you, making it simpler to use for background tasks.
You could use BackgroundService which is a bit more convenient since it's a base class that simplifies some of the implementation details.
BackgroundService:
public class QueueProcessor : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly MessageQueue _queue;

    public QueueProcessor(MessageQueue queue)
    {
        _queue = queue;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var message = await _queue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            if (message != null)
            {
                ProcessMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing: {message}");
    }
}



public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MessageQueue>();  
    services.AddHostedService<QueueProcessor>();
}

To run multiple instances of the QueueProcessor, you would normally add multiple services. With BackgroundService, you can also run multiple

Thank you for you comments, these are very usefull, just another question, so how would I create multiple instances of QueueProcessor to continously read the queue, and is this the best approach?

@KSingh To create multiple instances of QueueProcessor that continuously read from the queue, you need to register each instance of the service separately. you need to explicitly create and manage multiple instances.

Implement your service, e.g., QueueProcessor, which processes messages from a queue in the ExecuteAsync method. Register multiple instances using factory methods in ConfigureServices. Example:services.AddSingleton<MessageQueue>(); services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(provider => new QueueProcessor(provider.GetRequiredService<MessageQueue>())); services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(provider => new QueueProcessor(provider.GetRequiredService<MessageQueue>()));
